# Win 10 Git does not track files modification but does track new files

Tags: git

I am new to git (git version 2.34.1.windows.1) then please be patient with me.

I have the following local repository that has been successfully pushed into GitHub.

> Test/ 
> Test/Folder1 
> Test/Folder2/.xml
>
> Test/Submodule1 
> Test/Submodule1/FolderA/FolderA1 
> Test/Submodule1/FolderA/.html

Now if I create new files (touch) I have no issue and git does recognize them then I am able to git add and git commit them. However, if I modify any file in any directory (EX: .xml or .html) they are not recognized as changed (I saved the modifications).

I have tried to set core.ignoreStat = false, but it does create a new core.ignoreStat keeping the other, then I end up with two core.ignoreStat configurations.

Any idea.

P.S. Make modifications on GitHub and git submodule update work. Only solution I have found to make it works from local is to remove .git and re-initialize everything.

Comment: tried deleting `.gitignore` file?

Comment: @LeiYang, I gave it a try but still unable to track changes inside files, only new files are tracked.

Comment: You can try to run `git status --ignored` to see if the files are ignored.

Comment: @Robert_Hall. They are not ignored. I see that if I try to git submodule update it asks me to commit the files I have modified, however when I try git status or add/commit it says updated

Comment: If running `git submodule update` does stuff, you have submodules. When you have submodules, you have multiple Git repositories, which explains a lot: the files you're modifying aren't in *this* Git repository at all. (Files in your working tree aren't in a repository, but did come out of one: but these files came out of a *different* Git repository.)

Comment: @torek Not sure what u are saying. However, submodules are git repository too. The upper repository Test is a git repository not a submodule then following your rational I should be able to track change within it, at least, but I cannot. If you can suggest any command to solve the issue I'd be happy to test it, like that I have not enough information to try something.

Comment: If `test` is a submodule within the *current* repository, you must navigate *out of the current repository, into the submodule repository*. For instance, run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, then `cd test`, then `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`. If the result are different from the two `git rev-parse` commands, you're now in the *inner* (submodule) repository and can add and commit files from the working tree for *this* repository.

Comment: Once you `cd` back out to the *superproject* repository, you can add and commit a *gitlink* for the submodule, to record the current commit hash ID as stored *in the submodule*. Before you do that, though, note that you'll need to `git push` any new commit(s) you made *in* that submodule Git to whatever other place (GitHub?) stores the "source of truth" version of that submodule repository.

Comment: @tarek test is a repository. Submodule is a submodule. But thank I'll try the same procedure for the submodule folder. However it sound strange that new file are tracked but not file modifications.

Comment: @torek There are two top/upper level. One is Test (*superproject* with submodules within) and the other is Submodule1. If I get inside any of this "repository" the issue is the following I add new files fine they are tracked and I can git add/commit but If I open the file and modified it I cannot add/commit because it does not see them as changed

Comment: The "outer" Git repository *does not and cannot* store any files from the "inner" Git repository. Instead, the outer (superproject) stores only a *reference to a specific commit within* the inner repository.

Comment: Hence, if you wish to store some new version of some file that lives in the "inner" repository, you must enter that repository, add the file there, and commit it there. (Then `git push` if / as needed. Note that the inner repository is in *detached HEAD* mode because of the superproject's existence, so you must compensate for that.)

Comment: Once you've made a new commit *in* the *inner* (submodule) repository, you can `git add` in the outer (superproject) to record the *hash ID* of the inner commit, in the outer repository's proposed next commit. An eventual `git commit` in the superproject will now record the new commit hash ID for the submodule.

Comment: @torek Maybe I wasn't clear but you cannot add/commit something is untracked and here it's the issue. Look leave it aside the submodule. Main repository, I have a file that I do modify, I cannot add or commit because if you use git status there is not  recorded change. You are talking about push 2 steps ahead of my issue/question

Comment: A file is untracked if it's not in Git's index, but a file that's in a submodule cannot become tracked because Git won't add a path that's contained within a sub-repository of the current repository. That is, if I am standing in directory `A` and there is a file named `A/B`, a directory named `A/B/C`, a directory named `A/B/C/.git`, and a file named `A/B/C/D`, I can make file `A/B` tracked or not as I wish (with `git add` and/or `git rm`) but file `A/B/C/D` will forever be untracked *unless* I first *remove* `A/B/C/.git`.

Comment: Meanwhile, I can run `(cd A/B/C; git add D)` and that will add `D` to the Git repository in `C`: if it's already tracked there, it's updated, and if it was untracked there, it is now tracked there. So now I can commit with `D` in the repository that resides in `A/B/C`, and *once I do that* I can `git add A/B/C` to add the gitlink to `A/.git` for `A/B/C`.

Comment: If I choose to remove the `A/B/C` *repository* entirely (`rm -rf A/B/C/.git`), all the working tree files within `A/B/C` become eligible for being tracked within the `A/.git` repository, because I'm now down to a single repository.

Comment: If this *isn't* your situation, you may have found a bug in Git-for-Windows.

Comment: @torek I had a bit of time to try to clone the repository into my Mac and there it works just fine.